# Check present validators inside custom reactive from component

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Inside one of my form components, say `MyParentFormComponent`, I need to know which validators are used by its parent component For example

```
const fc = new FormControl('', [Validators.email, Validators.required]);
```

So, in my form control component I would like to know that these two validators are present. The reason why is that this custom from component is a wrapper around other form components, so I would like to pass these validators on to its children.

So, I have tried:

```
export MyParentFormComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {
    @Input() formControlName: string;

    constructor(@Optional() private controlContainer: ControlContainer) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        const control = this.controlContainer.control.get(formFieldName);
        const validators = control.validator(''); // problems!!!
    }
}
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6dmn2c?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmy-custom-form-control%2Fmy-custom-form-control.component.ts)

First, the `control.validator` function does not expects a string, in my IDE I get the following message:

[image]

Apparently it would like an AbstractControl. But when I fix this error as follows

```
control.validator('' as any);
```

it returns

```
{ required: true }
```

it only contains the `Validators.required`. All others are not in there.

So I get the feeling that this might not be the right path to obtain the validators information. Any suggestion how I can get this list?

UPDATE: `control.validator` is not a property but a function

[image]

Comment: I suppose you need add a `@Host()` to the constructor.NOTE: validator is a property, not a method, so you need remove the parenthesis: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl

Comment: you can also inject in constructor the NgControl

Comment: It is really a function, I've created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6dmn2c?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmy-custom-form-control%2Fmy-custom-form-control.component.ts) which demonstrated the issue as well

Comment: Why don't simply use `control.validator` in `setValidators` method?

Comment: I get the impression it is not possible anyway: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13461

Comment: Ive updated my post in which I show that `control.validator` is a function. I've also added a stackblitz

Comment: Yes, it is a function and we can pass it to `AbstractControl.setValidators` method. You won't see the real validators added to the control